# How Can I Have Multiple Executables In A Single Swift 3 Package?

Tags: swift3

I'm doing [Advent Of Code](http://adventofcode) and have each day's project in one Swift package so I can easily share pieces between them. Each day produces its own executable, `day01`, `day02`, and so on.

My package is laid out like so:

```
$ tree
.
├── Package.swift
├── Sources
│   ├── SomethingShared
│   │   └── Shared.swift
│   ├── day01
│   │   └── main.swift
│   └── day02
│       └── main.swift
└── Tests
    ├── SomethingSharedTests
    │   └── SharedTest.swift
    ├── day01Tests
    │   └── day01Test.swift
    └── day02Tests
        └── day02Test.swift
```

This builds fine, but the tests won't link with more than one `main.swift`.

```
$ swift test
Compile Swift Module 'SomethingShared' (1 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'day02Tests' (1 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'day01Tests' (1 sources)
Linking ./.build/debug/day01
Linking ./.build/debug/day02
Compile Swift Module 'SomethingSharedTests' (1 sources)
Linking ./.build/debug/AdventOfCode2016PackageTests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/AdventOfCode2016PackageTests
duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/schwern/tmp/foo/.build/debug/day01.build/main.swift.o
    /Users/schwern/tmp/foo/.build/debug/day02.build/main.swift.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/schwern/tmp/foo/.build/debug.yaml test
```

It seems like it's trying to link the `main` functions into one library.

How can I prevent this? Alternatively, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Here is [a zip of the test project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8332480/AdventOfCode2016.zip) if you want to look at the contents, there isn't much there. [Here is my real project](https://github.com/schwern/adventofcode2016) if you'd like to see what I'm doing.